# Using FFMPEG: How to reorder scenes within a single video file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to detect scene changes in a video file, then rearrange (randomly or otherwise) those scenes and output an MP4. Is this doable with FFMPEG?

Comment: Yes. Check out `select`, `trim` and `concat` filters of ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks, looking into those!